# SQL join to return results only if all rows match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

this is my first time on the site so please be gentle. I have tried to find my answer here, but nothing seems to fit the bill and after reading up on different types of joins, I'm still none the wiser.

I have the following tables:

```
employees (employee_id, name)
assessments (assessment_id, name, pass_score)
authorizations (authorization_id, name)
```

Employees take assessments which is logged in:

```
assessments_taken (assessment_taken_id, employee_id, assessment_id, score)
```

An authorization is composed of multiple individual assessments given by:

```
authorization_requirements (auth_req_id, authorization_id, assessment_id)
```

where `authorization_id` & `assessment_id` are unique constraints to prevent duplicates of the pair.

The query I am trying to design is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT employees.name, authorization.name ...
```

I only want to return  employees and authorizations where an employee has passed all assessments for that authorization given in **authorization_requirements**.

Can anyone help me find the query/sub-queries I am looking for?

Comment: Which db you are using

Comment: does the OP not specify mysql in the tags?

Comment: @MrCoder, they also specify mssql.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko must be missing something cause I can't see that?

Comment: @MrCoder, the "sql-server" tag is for mssql.

Comment: OP must be using MySQL. It is common mistake that people did not realize that sql-server means "Microsoft SQL Server" but rather any sql database server products like Oracle, DB2, MySQL etc

Comment: Make authorization_requirements as base table

Comment: @Orion I have the option of using MS-Access, MySQL, or MSSQL, so a general or specific approach would be helpful. Is this the correct way of organizing the tables or could it do with a redesign? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac7887/2

I think this query will do it for you. It relies on there only being one entry in the Assessments Taken per employee per assessment. If employees can take the assessments multiple times and all results are recorded in this table, there's a second query that should work for you.

```
SELECT
  Employees.name Employee,
  authorizations.name Authorization
FROM
  employees
  CROSS JOIN authorizations
  INNER JOIN authorization_requirements ON authorizations.authorization_id = authorization_requirements.authorization_id
  INNER JOIN assessments ON authorization_requirements.assessment_id = assessments.assessment_id
  LEFT JOIN assessments_taken ON employees.employee_id = assessments_taken.employee_id AND assessments.assessment_id = assessments_taken.assessment_id AND assessments.pass_score <= assessments_taken.score
GROUP BY
  Employees.name,
  authorizations.name
HAVING
  COUNT(assessments.assessment_id) = COUNT(assessments_taken.assessment_taken_id)
```

If multiple entries in assessments_taken:

```
SELECT
  Employees.name Employee,
  authorizations.name Authorization
FROM
  employees
  CROSS JOIN authorizations
  INNER JOIN authorization_requirements ON authorizations.authorization_id = authorization_requirements.authorization_id
  INNER JOIN assessments ON authorization_requirements.assessment_id = assessments.assessment_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               assessments_taken.employee_id,
               assessments_taken.assessment_id,
               MAX(Score) best_score
             FROM
               assessments_taken
             GROUP BY
               assessments_taken.employee_id,
               assessments_taken.assessment_id
             ) best_assessments_taken ON employees.employee_id = best_assessments_taken.employee_id AND assessments.assessment_id = best_assessments_taken.assessment_id AND assessments.pass_score <= best_assessments_taken.best_score
GROUP BY
  Employees.name,
  authorizations.name
HAVING
  COUNT(assessments.assessment_id) = COUNT(best_assessments_taken.assessment_id)
```

These queries get every employee and authorization and then ensure that the employee has got an entry in assessments_taken which exceeds the required score for every assessment specified in authorization_requirements

If `CROSS JOIN` is not supported you might need to put those two tables in a sub query and then change the join conditions to reference the columns from the sub query instead:

```
SELECT
  employee_authorizations.employee_name Employee,
  employee_authorizations.authorization_name Authorization
FROM
  (SELECT
        employees.employee_id,
        employees.name employee_name,
        authorizations.authorization_id,
        authorizations.name authorization_name
  FROM
        employees,
        authorizations) employee_authorizations
  INNER JOIN authorization_requirements ON employee_authorizations.authorization_id = authorization_requirements.authorization_id
  INNER JOIN assessments ON authorization_requirements.assessment_id = assessments.assessment_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               assessments_taken.employee_id,
               assessments_taken.assessment_id,
               MAX(Score) best_score
             FROM
               assessments_taken
             GROUP BY
               assessments_taken.employee_id,
               assessments_taken.assessment_id
             ) best_assessments_taken ON employee_authorizations.employee_id = best_assessments_taken.employee_id AND assessments.assessment_id = best_assessments_taken.assessment_id AND assessments.pass_score <= best_assessments_taken.best_score
GROUP BY
  employee_authorizations.employee_name,
  employee_authorizations.authorization_name
HAVING
  COUNT(assessments.assessment_id) = COUNT(best_assessments_taken.assessment_id)
```

Comment: What modifications do I need to enable this to work with MSAccess as it doesn't like CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @MatthewO'Sullivan I've updated with an alternate version if CROSS JOIN isn't supported

Comment: Thanks @Tobsey, It works great in sqlfiddle but testing it within MS-Access 2010 is giving me grief as I think I'm missing the brackets which MS-Access needs for JOINS. I'm applying liberal use of brackets now and will post what I have when it starts playing nice. Thankyou.

Answer (score 5):

The below image may help you somewhat in learning SQL joins - it even gives you some of the SQL itself!. As for the **authorization_requirements** it sounds like you'll need to be using some WHERE clause along with the join.

Hope this helps, and any clarification, please feel free to ask!

[image: Sql Join]